# What's the minimum reasonable thickness for subfloor in my attic?

Tags: plywood, subfloor

I want to install 4x8 sheets of T&G plywood in my attic for extra storage room, but there are so many different thicknesses.  There will be extremely minimal traffic on this floor as I will only be up there once or twice a year and for no more than 30 minutes to an hour at a time.

Comment: how are you going to get 4x8 sheets into an existing attic? (unless this attic is under construction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always be safe now rather than sorry later. For the small difference is cost, use  3/4 inch sheathing or underlayment.  There are several good T&G underlayment brands out there, but T&G may be a little over kill for your application. Simple sheathing, CDX or underlayment should work fine.

Comment: By underlayment, are you talking about something like 1/4" board that is used for things like vinyl application?  I can't find any 3/4" sheathing, but I assume 23/32" would work just as well?

Comment: in today's market, 23/32 is what we call 3/4 inch.

Comment: No! not 1/4" vinyl and tile underlayment,  I should have said sub-flooring.  yes 23/32"

Comment: I decided to get 23/32" T&G OSB since the T&G cost was not that much more.  Plus, T&G just makes me feel better in case I ever decide to further finish my attic in the future.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the distance between joists or trusses, and the weight of the boxes/items you intend to store there. I personally would not use less than 1/2", and probably at least 5/8".